# Functions, Options and Symbols

Tags: symbols

In the normal *Mathematica* language, where no built-in symbols are redefined and no evil things happen, is it a valid assumptions, that no function symbol (`Plot`, `Print`, `Attributes`) is also an option name (like `PlotRange`, `ColorSpace`, `ImageSize`). Furthermore, is it save to assume that symbols carrying an `OwnValue` (`$MaxNumber`, `Pi`, `$Failed`) are in neither of the other two groups?

To say it straight out: Does someone find a function, which is used as an option too?

Comment: Consider `PlotRange[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]`...

Comment: @J.M. This is an incredible nice counter example!

Comment: @ J.M. `PlotRange` is definitely dcumented **only** as an option.  How did you figure this one out?  It is also not a general means for retrieving `Options` values.  Very nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question can be answered programmatically, at least to some extent. If we restrict ourselves to `` System` `` context only, then:

```
names = Names["System`*"];

optnames = 
  Quiet@Union@
     Cases[
       ToExpression[
          #, 
          StandardForm, 
          Function[name, Options[Unevaluated[name]], HoldAll]
       ] & /@  names, 
       (name_Symbol -> _) :> Hold[name], 
       Infinity];

symbols = 
    ToExpression[
        #, 
        StandardForm, 
        Function[name, 
           If[SyntaxInformation[Unevaluated@name] =!= {}, Hold@name, {}], 
           HoldAll]
        ] & /@ names;

Intersection[optnames,symbols]

(*  {Hold[Eliminate],Hold[NotebookFileName],Hold[Sort],Hold[TimeZone],Hold[Tooltip]} *)
```

where I assumed that a function is a symbol with a non-trivial value of `SyntaxInformation`. This is likely not the best criteria, but I think it is good enough, given that many system functions have their internal `...Values` not reflected by the `...Values` top-level functions.

My understanding has been that such symbols are rare and the parctice to have a symbol as both a function and a name of the option is generally discouraged. But such symbols do exist, and I have no doubts that there are many more instances than those found here, both because the criteria I used here may be too strict (for example, uses of symbols lile `PlotRange` as a function aren't documented and don't have non-trivial `SyntaxInformation` attached to them), and so I may have missed some, and also because they may exist in other contexts not considered here.

Your second question could be answered in a similar fashion: here are the symbols which have values (but not necessarily top-level `OwnValues`):

```
ownsymbols = 
   Cases[ 
      ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Hold] & /@ names, 
      Hold[s_] /; Hold[s] =!= Hold[Evaluate[s]]
   ];
```

we can now see if there is any overlap with the other two groups:

```
Intersection[ownsymbols,symbols]

(* {Hold[NotebookInformation]} *)

Intersection[ownsymbols,optnames]

(* {} *)
```

so, some symbols having a value apparently may be functions (although probably the dominant set of such use cases would be aliases, like in the case of `NotebookInformation`), while, at least among the `` System` `` functions, symbols standing for option names appear to not have values. We can probably expect this last conclusion to be true in general, since `Options` isn't `HoldAll`, and therefore the option names having (Own)values don't make much sense since they will evaluate to their values before being seen by `Options` and other option-related functions.

Finally, a number of functions which are implemented using the auto-loading mechanism, initiallu have `OwnValues` attached to their symbols, which then later get removed and replaced by `DownValues` and / or `SubValues`, once the function has been loaded. They never have both at the same time though.

Comment: Thanks Leonid. It's what I would have guessed. I think I will not care about the exceptions. I'm currently thinking about how to provide a *smart completion*. One part is to provide a nice way of inserting options when the parent AST-node is a function. Another part is that the smart completion add brackets when the symbol is known to be a function while only providing a normal expansion for things like $Failed.

Comment: @halirutan I did guess the origin of your question :)

Comment: Funny,It's seem I crash your answer. :)

Comment: @yode Your answer seems to give an alternative way to compute all symbols used as options. I don't have the time now to compare its result to mine, it could very well be that your method is more precise. But in the above post, I was concerned not just with options, but with symbols that are at the same time used for normal functions, as well as for options.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125388/how-to-get-the-parameter-number-of-inbuilt-function)? :)

Comment: @yode No, I have not. But I don't know a robust question to that answer, that would be better than the one suggested there.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin what do you know about the autoload mechanism? [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114956/38205) involves the autoload functionality, so maybe you can provide a better answer than the pieces I've cobbled together.

Comment: @MB1965 There are at least 2 different routes for autoloads, used by the system. One is used by the kernel and is based on ``System`Dump`Autoload``. The other one is used by the paclets / paclet manager, and is based on ``Package`ActivateLoad``, as explored in the answer you linked. I don't have the time at the moment for a longer answer, but the idea behind the autoloading mechanism is rather straightforward in both cases - you create an `OwnValue` for the symbol that would load its definition, along with possible other related ones, upon the first call, prior to returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is unnecessary think,but I have thought it many times,too.Of course,I feel confusion about the [J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22868/functions-options-and-symbols#comment71104_22868).(Mr. J.M. is wonderful man who always break up my concept that have shape long time. :)).So I sure some built-in function is classified as *option* by *WR*.In an certain time,you can get this class of *function* by:

```
EntityClassList["WolframLanguageSymbol"]
```

But I cannot reproduce it now(I'm in version 11.0.1),I don't sure the low version `MMA` can reproduce it or not.There is two screenshot I keep:

- First

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-13-18-47-26.png

- Second
  http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-13-18-50-25.png

As we can see,there are $757$ function is classified as *option names*.After some thinking,I think this method can get all of *option names*:

```
Select[ToExpression[
  DeleteCases[
   CanonicalName[
    Complement[EntityList["WolframLanguageSymbol"], 
     EntityList[
      EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
       "Autoevaluating"]]]], _?(StringStartsQ["$"])]], 
 SyntaxInformation[#] == {} &]
```

> {Above,AccuracyGoal,ActiveStyle,AdjustmentBoxOptions,After,Algebraics,Alignment,AlignmentPoint,All,AllowedDimensions,AllowGroupClose,AllowInlineCells,AllowLooseGrammar,AllowReverseGroupClose,AlternateImage,AlternativeHypothesis,AltitudeMethod,AmbiguityFunction,AnchoredSearch,AnimationDirection,AnimationRate,AnimationRepetitions,AnimationRunning,AnimationRunTime,AnimationTimeIndex,Anonymous,Antialiasing,Appearance,AppearanceElements,...}

It's not $757$(Actually the number is $909$),but it's very colsely.