# What are Package` context symbols for?

Tags: packages, undocumented, internals

The `` Package` `` context contains the following:

[image]

What is the use of these undocumented functions?

**I am looking for a concise description of the syntax and purpose of the most prominent of these functions, accompanied by examples.**

---

I believe these are primarily used for the auto-loading mechanism of built-in symbols.  For example,

[image]

There are some references to these symbols within the Parallel Tools.  Spelunking reference: `` SystemOpen@DirectoryName[FindFile["Parallel`"], 2] ``.

The Paclet Manager may also use these [to set up auto-loading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12) of paclets.

This mechanism seems to be distinct from [`DeclarePackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfPackages.html).  `DeclarePackage` is rather rigid and doesn't make it easy to set up flexible auto-loading because it always executes `Needs`, which will not call `Get` twice for the same package.  I see no easy way to transition an existing single-context package to delayed loading by using only `DeclarePackage`.

---

I think it would be useful to spelunk the symbols in the Package context and produce some basic description for them, as well as basic instructions on how to set up auto-loading for packages.

Answer (score 8):

#### CreatePackageCache / AutoloadPackage

`CreatePackageCache` is called as

```
Package`CreatePackageCache[
 pkgContext,
 pkgDir,
 Package`AutloadPackage->boolean]
```

Where `pkgContext` is a package context declared in the new-style (so that it's possible to find via `PackageInformation`).

What this does is dumps what is presumably the package data to a .mx file in the `pkgDir`. If `AutoloadPackage` is specified it seems to load the package before dumping.

#### DeclareLoad / ActivateLoad / HiddenImport / ExportedContexts

`` Package`DeclareLoad `` is called as

```
Package`DeclareLoad[
 {symbols},
 context,
 Package`HiddenImport->boolean,
 Path->pathspec,
 Package`ExportedContexts->{contexts}]
```

it configures autoloading by setting

```
Package`ActivateLoad[
 symbol,
 {symbols},
 context,
 {Package`HiddenImport->boolean, Path->pathspec}
 ]
```

on each `symbol` in `symbols`, which in turn clears the `OwnValues` (and maybe the other `*Values`) of all the `symbols` and then loads the context by a `Get` like mechanism, searching in `Path`. Note that `` Package`ActivateLoad `` can be called on its own.

Still working out what happens to `` Package`ExportedContexts ``...

#### PackageInformation / LoadPackage / ForceLoad

`` Package`PackageInformation `` is used to get package information for packages declared in the new style. `` Package`ForceLoad `` is used by `` Package`PackageInformation `` to specify whether to load the package or not.

`` Package`LoadPackage `` loads these new-style packages, but not old-style one.

---

## Spelunking Updates

---

### Long Form

#### *Update 5*

`PackageImport`, `PackageScope`, and `PackageExport` all live in the `PackageDirectives` context which is presumable initialized by `LoadPackage`

#### *Update 4*

Figured out how to use `CreatePackageCache` based on knowing there are new-style declarations. Note that there must be `PackageInformation` for `pkgContext` otherwise your kernel will crash (or at least it has for me).

One oddity is that even though it creates the .mx file, it doesn't seem to be exporting the definitions for my symbols... Need to check this out.

#### *Update 3*

There is another symbol, `PackageImport` which works like `PackageExport` except it imports the package. One thing worth noting about these new-style packages is that it seems their init files always call `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` still.

#### *Update 2*

By running `PackageInformation/@Contexts[]` I found that there is a new package declaration style as visible in the `` Macros` ``, `` Iconize` ``, and `` TextSearch` `` packages.

I made my a package stub in this style:

```
Package["TestPKG`"]

PackageScope["blumpf"]
PackageExport["Blah"]
PackageExport["Blah2"]
```

And by saving this so somewhere included in `$Path` I could use `PackageInformation` on this too (although I had to allow `ForceLoad`. It also works with `LoadPackage` in a way that packages declared in the old style do not.

`PackageExport` puts the symbol into toplevel usage. `PackageScope` is the new `Private`. We can find more symbols like this by searching for `` Names["*`PackageScope`*"] `` after running `Get/@Contexts[]`

Need to do more searching for the symbols, but I think I'll start in these contexts.

#### *Update 1*

`` Package`DeclareLoad `` seems to be the main usage function. It takes a set of symbols that are prepped to autoload a set of packages. The loads can be "hidden" via `` Package`HiddenImport `` which just means the contexts don't get added to the `$ContextPath` it seems.

It can also take extra contexts to export via `` Package`ExportedContexts `` and a path to look for the package on (default `Automatic`).

This just configures `` Package`ActivateLoad `` in the `OwnValues` of the symbols, which simply acts as a fancy `Get` mechanism.

It looks like:

```
Package`ActivateLoad[loadMyTools,
 {loadMyTools},
 "MyTools`",
 {Package`HiddenImport -> True, Path -> Automatic}]
```

for example. The second argument are all the other symbols declared in the same `DeclareLoad` the third is the set of packages, etc. Pretty clear.

---

Here are the places I've searched so far, so that others can look through them too:

```
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/MXNetLink/*.m
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/NeuralNetworks/*.m
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/Iconize/*.m
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/Macros/*.m
$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Applications/Parallel/Kernel/sysload.m
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel/Documentation.m
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel/Manager.m 
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86-64/sysinit.m
```

Comment: In fact I did give pointers to where to spelunk for internal usages of these functions, mentioning both the parallel tools and the paclet manager. Thus I am aware of what you described in your original post.  The reason why I set the bounty was that I hoped that someone would do the spelunking and write a concise, easy to understand answer, that shows how to use the most important functions and gives concrete usage examples. *I'd like to have an answer which is easy to read for a large audience* and doesn't go into the intricacies of spelunking. Can you please update yours to read like that?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll pare it down to the basics

Comment: @MB1965 Very interesting, but what are packages in the new style? Is it only that there is a file PacletInformation.m?

Comment: @FredSimons the PacletInformation.m simply specifies that it's a Mathematica application. Packages in the old style would use `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage`. In the new style we declare a package with `Package` and use the `Package*` family of functions to define it. Then `LoadPackage` can be used to load such a package. Check out `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/Macros/*.m` to see examples of this.

Comment: @MB1965. Thanks! I am highly surprised. Never seen a package not using `BeginPackage` - `EndPackage`. The guide `Package Development` does not mention the new style. So far, it seems to be completely undocumented. Do you think this new style is meant to replace the old style sooner or later?

Comment: @FredSimons I think it exists to complement the old style. If you look at how the ``Macros` `` package is built it does use a `BeginPackage` in its main package file. However this new style is potentially easier to work with and the more declarative style allows for better introspection--e.g. as done with `PackageInformation` here. Eventually I'm sure it will make its way into documented functionality. For now we can simply work off of the examples that WRI has already built into the system.

Comment: @MB1965. Thanks again! I am going to play with it.