# Declaring Package with dependencies in multiples files?

Tags: packages

I am new to using Mathematica where I write most of my code in packages.

So to get the hang of it I am trying to set up an example of what a project might actually look like.

```
/TestPackage
/TestPackage.m (* top level package code goes here *)
/Component1
/Component1/foo.m (* some functions belonging to component 1*)
/Component1/bar.m (* some other functions belonging to component 1*)
/Component1/Component1.m (* mid level package code goes here*)
/Component2/Component2.m (* mid level package code goes here*)
```

Where `TestPackage` needs functions from both of the components, and `Component1` requires functions that have been split into the smaller files `foo.m` and `bar.m`

For a single file package I can do:

```
BeginPackage[<pkg-name>`]
(* stuff here *)
EndPackage[]
```

but how can I do the relative depedencies?

**Aside**

Why ask this question?

Well looking at this documentation:

https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html

> If you want to develop several applications which refer to each other, you can do this using project references. Suppose that you have two applications, App1 and App2. Furthermore, App1 needs functions from App2, for example, it contains the declaration BeginPackage["App1", "App2"].

(What I suggest above)

> When you run or debug the project for App1 the Workbench will add the source for App2 so that this gets used as well.

Which sounds odd, as often times a package is split into different levels and the lower levels are sequestered away. From the above documentation it sounds like those lower levels should be elevated, or given Smurf naming e.g. `MyPackageSubComponentUtilities` rather than `MyPackage/SubComponent/Utilities.m`

In the same documentation, under "Multiple Packages":

[image]

is the recommended way to do multiple packages.

Which to me means that perhaps my question is due to a lexical misunderstanding. Maybe what I am trying to write is a level lower than a Mathematica Package, more akin to a python module...

Now it could be that these are just outdated docs that persist, so I have also gone through the circular links in the new docs, with closest thing I have found being the scantly linked to:

[Files For Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesForPackages.html)

which doesn't really say anything (I can understand in context of answering my question) but the brief allude to the context searching for `/dir` last.

and the tutorial [Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html) does not address anything more advanced than a single file package.

any help would be appreciated.

The answer provided for sub-context's [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/301/42578) suggests it involves subtlety and workbench :/

Comment: I handle this by having a top-level loader that loads all files and manages the appropriate contexts so that I can implement the package at low level however I like and then only expose some small public interface. See [this](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-PublicPacletServer/blob/master/PublicPacletServerLoader.m) for an example of this can work. It has served me quite well and is honestly very similar to how python manages these things.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I appreciate your assistance, but not quite sure how to make use of your 2166 line public packet server and the readme is a bit sparse :P Quick follow up, what is difference between paclet vs package?

Comment: That file I linked was all I intended you to care about. It has a section on loading the package in it where you can see how it walks through the files and makes sure the context is working. The package itself is a utility package for a paclet server we set up. And a paclet is a Mathematica package that people can actually use. See Szabolcs’ Q/As on the site for more on that. If you write Mathematica code, though, you should really make it a paclet.

Comment: Related closed question: ["Multipart package creation, development and maintenance"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172074/34008).

Answer (score 39):

## Preamble

I will interpret your question as a general question on how one can organize multi-file projects in Mathematica / WL. There are two main axes in this problem, and they are

- Loading procedure / loading sequence
- Namespace / context management

To the first approximation, one can treat these independently. However, any complete solution will provide some solutions for both which might be interdependent, so I will consider them together.

## Simplest case: multi-fragment (multi-file) project, single namespace

This is more or less what is suggested in the tutorial you mentioned. In this scheme, there is a single public context `` MyProject` `` and (usually) a single private context `` MyProject`Private` ``, just like in a single-file package. However, the code is split into several files / fragments.

While there is a single public and private namespace, a split to several fragments requires one to have a fragment that would declare all public / exported symbols, even if their implementation will live in a different fragment, and to load that fragment before any others.

Since `init.m` file is present in the `Kernel` sub-folder, it is an entry point, and you are free to customize everything in that `init.m`. There are two main variations one can employ in this scheme

### Namespace-aware fragments

You load all fragments within `init.m` using `Get`, one after another.

This method has the following advantages:

- Project's loading sequence is explicit and declarative.
- It will be easier to statically analyze, if such a need arises
- One doesn't need to use the `$InputFileName` variable and absolute paths

But every fragment would need to separately wrap the code into `BeginPackage` - `EndPackage`, as well as `` Begin["`Private`"] `` - `End[]` for the private section, which one may consider as a disadvantage.

### One master fragment and N slave fragments

You only load your main fragment within `init.m` with `Get`, and inside the main fragment `` Private` `` section you load all other fragments.

This method couples project's loading with execution of implementation code, but then you don't need to assign a namespace for each fragment - if you load it inside the first / main fragment `` Private` `` section, other fragments may contain just the code, and will automatically be parsed into `` Private` `` context - so that in this approach only the main fragment needs  the structure `BeginPackage` - `EndPackage`, as well as `` Begin["`Private`"] `` - `End[]`.

It is however less declarative, and one would need to use the `$InputFileName` and absolute paths to load other fragments.

### Problems solved and not solved in this approach

The main problems that this approach solves:

- It is much more convenient to work with smaller source files
- One can split code according to the different functionality, making it easier to reason about

The problems this approach does not solve

- Name collisions between private symbols: since there is still a single public and single private namespaces, one may forget that a given private symbol has been defined in one fragment and define it again for a completely different purpose.
- No real modularization: even though code is split into fragments, the developer is not encouraged to minimize fragment's interdependencies, avoid circular dependencies, etc. Moreover, even if the code has pieces which are completely independent from each other, single namespace does not allow one to really separate them well enough.

## New-style packages: undocumented modern way of structuring multi-fragment packages

With a usual disclaimer that one can't rely on undocumented functionality, and can use it at one's own risk only, let me briefly describe the new package format (AFAIK, available since V10).

### Project's structure

In this format, the project typically has a flat structure, similar to the structure you mentioned:

```
MyProject    
  Kernel
    init.m
  Main.m
  ExtraTools.m
  Utilities.m
```

The folder `Kernel/init.m` is optional, if one of the fragments is named the same as the project's folder, in the above case would be `MyProject.m`. One can, however, still use `Kernel/init.m`, if one wants some other fragment to run first.

Note that one doesn't need to load manually all the fragments - this is done automatically by `Get`, for a new-style package, so it is enough to only indicate the fragment that you want to run first.

### Syntax and scoping

In this format, you split your package into several fragments, each of which has to start with a declaration:

```
Package["MyPackage`"]
```

In this format, you don't need to wrap the code in `BeginPackage` - `EndPackage` or `Begin` - `End`. Instead, if you want to make your symbol public (i.e. having the context `` MyPackage` ``), you write

```
PackageExport["MySymbol"]
```

anywhere in the file / fragment (in fact, it does not matter in which fragment even, although it is more logical usually to do that in the one where you implement that symbol).

There is one additional level of scope in this format, which is package scope. Package-scoped symbols are available to all fragments in the package, but not exported to the end user. You declare them as

```
PackageScope["MyInnerSharedSymbol"]
```

Package-scoped symbols live in `` MyProject`PackageScope` `` context.

If you want to import other packages, you use `PackageImport`, which is an analog of `Needs`:

```
PackageImport["DatabaseLink`"]
```

typically one does that at the start of the fragment, after `Package` declaration. You shouldn't use `Needs` in place of `PackageImport` in this format.

All symbols that are not exported, not package-scope, and not in any of the imported packages, are considered private. The difference with the standard format, however, is that each fragment has its own private context, so that private contexts of different fragments are different and don't collide. For example, for a fragment named `ExtraTools.m`, the private context will be `` MyPackage`ExtraTools`PackagePrivate` ``, while for fragment `Utilities.m`, it will be `` MyPackage`Utilities`PackagePrivate` ``. This separation of private sub-contexts is also why package-scoped symbols become necessary, as a way to privately communicate between different fragments.

### How it works, and a few gotchas

#### How it works (brief summary)

The way this format works is different from the standard one, where all contexts of all symbols were determined at run-time. Here, all fragments are first analyzed statically, to determine which symbols should be created in which contexts. During that analysis, dependencies (packages imported using `PackageImport`) are loaded dynamically, so one probably can't call it fully static. After all symbols get resolved, the fragments are actually run.

#### Why `Needs` can not be used

The above makes it more understandable, why `Needs` should not be used in place of `PackageImport` - the code using `Needs` will execute too late, after all static analysis would have been already performed, and so imported symbols won't have a chance to resolve in time, and in code of the package would be instead considered private symbols).

#### Loading order

Unfortunately, one can't easily control the fragments execution order, which is alphabetical in fragments names. One can, however, point `Get` in the `init.m` to a specific fragment, to ensure that that one will be executed first - and then all the rest in the alphabetical order of their names.

If you must enforce specific loading order, you can mangle fragments names, adding letters `A`, `B` etc. in front, to ensure that their alphabetical order corresponds to the order in which you actually want them to be loaded. However, one might argue that dependence of very specific loading order for several fragments is evil, and a sign of bad design.

#### A pitfall with declaration statements

It is important to point out is that statements `PackageExport`, `PackageScope`, `PackageImport` are actually tokens for a static analyzer, rather than real Mathematica code. In particular, wrapping them into anything won't work:

```
PackageImport["MyOtherPackage`"];
```

or

```
If[var === val, PackageExport["MySymbol"]]
```

won't work (the semicolon at the end is a very common error).

#### Per-fragment nature of `PackageImport`

Regarding `PackageImport`, one non-obvious thing is that a package, imported in one fragment, is not considered imported in others. This means that, if you use some package in several fragments of your new-style package, you need to `PackageImport` it in all of them, even though they are parts of the same big package you are developing. This behavior has both pros and cons, although it may often seem an inconvenience.

### Problems solved and not solved in this approach

The main problems that this approach solves:

- All of the problems that the simpler approach solves
- Better encapsulation: no collisions between private symbols of different fragments
- Somewhat better modularization: the fact that one can't use private symbols of one fragment in the other fragment, forces one to more carefully separate the interface from implementation. One is given the tool of package-scoped symbols to use for such communication, but you will be better off reducing their number to a necessary minimum

Problems still not solved in this approach

- Still better level of modularization can only be achieved when symbols belonging to different structural parts, live in different namespaces
- The new-style package format as such does not scale well when the amount and complexity of code grows. This is so both because it does not provide a true multi-level modularization, and because individual modules are not separately reloadable or otherwise self-contained (for example, can't be tested in isolation).

Still, this method is a huge step in the right direction, and for most small to medium or even large projects can be enough.

## Multi-package projects

If your code base really becomes large and complex, you may want to upgrade to a more flexible and powerful structure. The basic idea is to make different modules of your project independent full-fledged packages. For each individual module, one can use any of the methods I described earlier. One would also need a few additional pieces such as custom loader and probably an interface section.

I will describe this method in more detail, if there is enough interest.

## Conclusions

Depending on one's needs and also stylistic preferences,  one can use a number of different schemes to scale up the code and create multi-file projects. I have described a few methods that should do it for most user-level projects.

Comment: Don't know how much interest is enough so let me say that I am interested. Especially if that would cover versioned paclets or including 3rd party packages as   internal ones (unique context etc).

Comment: Suppose that the functions of a package naturally split into two sets. Let's take an attempt at modularization and break this package into two packages. But then I discover that both sets of *public* functions depend on a common set of *private* functions that will never be exposed. What's the best way to proceed?

Comment: @Kuba Can't help with versioned paclets, they don't exist yet AFAIK. Including third-party packages as internal ones - won't work either at the moment, if you want generality, because currently there is no way to have two incompatible versions of the same package loaded into the system at the same time without conflicts. But point taken, I will try to expand at least with a few more things that might be useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs [1/2] What we do in my current project is to split the project into several modules, each of which is an independent package with context being a sub-context of the main one. Then we have public interface of the project. Modules may depend on other modules, that's perfectly fine. Whenever I need to expose some of the internal module's function in some way as a public function, I define a proxy wrapper, that more or less delegates to that module's function, adding some error-handling. This process can be automated. All public functions for modules are considered inner functions for...

Comment: @Szabolcs [2/2] ... the main project. They are allowed to throw exceptions.  All proxied public functions catch all inner exceptions. So, in your example, we would have public interface, plus 3 sub-modules A, B and C. Both A and B will have public function which will depend on C (its exported public functions). If we want to expose some of the public functions from A and / or  B, we create proxies for them (on a very basic level, a proxy is just a wrapper like ``PublicF[args___]:= A`F[args]``, and expose that. We have a constructor for the proxy, which is something like `makeProxy[def]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Custom loader could overload `BeginPackage` and friends to load as ``TemplateApply["GeneralUtilities<*RandomInteger[10^15]*>`"]``, then having that we need to agree to a postfix convention for sem ver paclets and we are done. Few assumptions about package coding style would be needed but otherwise seems plausible to do, what do you think?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I appreciate the detailed answer (still going through it and trying to understand it) and would also be interested in the mutli-package... because I still do not see how to do relative imports of modules / packages

Comment: @Kuba Probably true. But I will need to think it over to have a more definite opinion. A good solution should implement proper versioning, deal with autoloading, also some dependencies may be MX-fied (in which case they will load directly into certain contexts, which probably means that the versioning scheme should also be wired into the distribution mechanism (basically, loader is not enough, one would also need MX-fier that would put things in proper contexts like ``GeneralUtilities$10$1$3` `` ( I used `$` sign as a version index separators). There are other things to consider too.

Comment: @Kuba There is currently an effort underway internally to solve these problems and come up with a modern package format. I however don't think that we have to wait for the moment when that new format emerges, gets tested and becomes official - that can easily take another year or two. We can start by creating a chat room here, devoted to this topic, or may be create a Slack channel (which is probably a better option). I will try to expand my answer in the next few days, to give more details on my current way of doing multi-package projects.

Comment: @SumNeuron I will try to expand my answer in that direction in the next day or two.

Comment: Here's a related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176627/how-to-design-re-usable-sub-modules

Comment: All the "problems solved" by this new approach seem to be problems inherent in the "Master-Slave" approach but not in the standard "Namespace-BeginPackage" approach while all the "problems still not solved" are ones that seem to be already solved in the  "Namespace-BeginPackage" approach - hence I can't quite see  why you consider this to be a "huge step in the right direction"?

Comment: @RonaldMonson There are two points which I outlined there: better encapsulation for private symbols in multi-fragment files and somewhat better modularization, achieved by the package-scope level and complete insulation of private contexts of different fragments. These things together lead to better code, and are IMO a step in the right direction. How huge that step is, depends on who you ask, but I personally like the new format much better exactly for above reasons.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [1/2]  doesn't `Private` already provide this encapsulation so that the better modularization is "only" to the extent that `BeginPackage`/`Begin` wrappers and `Need`'s calls (for the same-directory fragments) are being dispensed with? I agree that their remains much upside still available from greater modularization in general Mma code so perhaps this simplification should not be underestimated (not to mention advantages from having available softer, developer-focussed exporting). On the other hand ...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [2/2] ... for me, name collisions within  `Private` contexts has never really been an issue since well before they might become one the code has been naturally fragmented into (sub)Package(s); This also raises the need for a Find/Replace mechanism across files in the same directory and I also wonder about losing `Need`'s ability to avoid double-loading and where `DeclarePackage` fits in?

Comment: @RonaldMonson When you split a project into several fragments, it becomes very easy to make collisions for private symbols in different fragments, when the code grows large. Single ``Private` `` subcontext is then hardly sufficient. Splitting into subpackages only because you want to split into fragments doesn't sound like the best solution generally, and the new-style package allows one to do the latter without the former. `Needs` still works the same way. For `DeclarePackage` I would need to check, but I think it should work the same way too, for new-style packages.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [1/3] Yes well "splitting into subpackages only because you want to split into fragments" pretty much sums up a lot of my workflow so IMP therein lies the real value of this new package format (npf): The potential to  fragment with finer granularity that might also lead to transitions from functions->fragments->(sub)packages. Pursuing this, and for those wanting to run the name-colliding gauntlet, it would be great to have a token in a fragment that specifies the same `MyPackage\`Private\`` context. This would permit an earlier, "fragmentation by file" that has its own value ...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [2/3]  ... (clarity of thought, smaller, non-corrupting files, versioning etc) but doesn't enforce "excessive"  "`PackageScope`" exports until users are ready to "fragment by context". Conversely, being able to transit from "fragmenting by (private) context " to "fragmenting by fully-fledged package"  perhaps also encapsulates a next fragmenting stage that in turn might contribute to attaining "true, multi-level modularization" needed for npf's scaling.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin [3/3] Finally, it's a bit tantalizing to equate npf with an experimental package that has been around for a few years when master spelunkers like b3m2a1 and Szabolcs [continue to spelunk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/what-are-package-context-symbols-for/133704#133704) :) Does there perhaps exist a simple walk through (packages to load etc.) for users wanting to give it a try?

Comment: @RonaldMonson I agree with most of your points. As to new package format, it is undocumented, so I don't think there is any walk through. But my description should be enough to start, and also there are components in Mathematica distribution present in their source form (rather than MX), written in this style - which is where one can also look for how it is used.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ok, thanks; +1 for bringing this to the community's attention and clarifying comments. One thing about the automatic loading though; it occurs to me that despite the convenience gained, what you are losing is potentially v. significant - the ability to load on demand via `DeclarePackage` (there is, I see the "AutoloadSymbols" key supplied to ``PacletManager`Package`loadWolframLanguageCode`` which possibly addresses this when `PacletInfo.m` is present (?) but loading on demand still doesn't seem infused).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is there a gotcha regarding ordering loading via *Kernel/init.m*? Loading any file in the package directory seems to trigger a loading of all the files in the directory *as well as* the *Kernel/init.m* file thereby creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @RonaldMonson Re: autoloading: if you mean new-style packages, one can still do the autoloading. One way is via paclets, as you mentioned. But I would have to look closer to say more, in particular it might indeed be that `DeclarePackage` would not work. Re: *Loading any file in the package directory seems to trigger a loading of all the files* - good point. Yes, this is true, and therefore, one should not attempt to load all fragments via `Get` in the `init.m` for new-style packages. That would not lead to an infinite loop, but each file would be loaded `N` times. Load just one file instead.

Answer (score 12):

This answer adheres to the outline in the section "Multi-package projects" of [Leonid's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176489/34008) (emphasis mine):

> If your code base really becomes large and complex, you may want to upgrade to a more flexible and powerful structure. The basic idea is to make **different modules of your project independent full-fledged packages**. [...] One would also need a few additional pieces such as **custom loader** and probably **an interface section.**

Below is (briefly) described the multi-package dependency, loading, and code generation of the package ["MonadicContextualClassification.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicContextualClassification.m), [1].

The goal of the package [1] is to provide a Domain Specific Language (DSL) for rapid specification of machine learning classification workflows.

### Package file structure

1. Packages import code section.

   - Here packages are imported from GitHub with `Import`.

     - (If the corresponding definitions are not already in the context.)
   - These are the mentioned above "independent full-fledged packages".

     - (They were developed before the package [1].)
     - (The package [1] provides a DSL that combines those "full-fledged packages.")
2. Package interface definitions code section.

   - Here after `BeginPackage` the `::usage` definitions are given.
   - This is the "interface section" mentioned above.
3. The private context declaration.
4. The declaration of the package contexts with `Needs` code section.

   - (For the contexts of the packages in the imports code section 1.)
5. Code generation section.

   - In this case with
     `` GenerateStateMonadCode["MonadicContextualClassification`ClCon",...] ``
   - This code generation code section together with the imports code section 1, correspond to the "custom loader" mentioned above.

     - (The package [2] generates the definitions of some of the functions of the package [1].)
6. Function implementations code section.

### Testing

The development of the package was done with two unit test files. (One with [hand-written unit tests](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/UnitTests/MonadicContextualClassification-Unit-Tests.wlt), the other with [randomly generated tests](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/UnitTests/MonadicContextualClassificationRandomPipelinesUnitTests.m). The latter is specific to the methodology behind the package functionality.)

The point is that unit tests are crucial when dealing with this kind of complex package dependencies. (And packages that deal with complex subjects.)

### Summary diagram

Below is given a diagram that summarizes the development of ["MonadicContextualClassification.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicContextualClassification.m). For more details see the end sections of the document ["A monad for classification workflows"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MarkdownDocuments/A-monad-for-classification-workflows.md).

[image: ClCon-development-cycle]

### Example run

The following screenshot is of an example run that demonstrates the package import prompts and the utilization of the loaded packages in a classification pipeline. (The packages have functionalities for training classifier ensembles, making ROC plots, and finding importance of variables.)

[image: ClCon-example-run-with-Import]

### References

[1] Anton Antonov, [Monadic contextual classification Mathematica package](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicContextualClassification.m), (2017), [MathematicaForPrediction at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/).

[2] Anton Antonov, [State monad code generator Mathematica package](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/StateMonadCodeGenerator.m), (2017), [MathematicaForPrediction at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/).

Comment: If you use the IDEA plugin, [could you comment on](https://gitter.im/Mathematica-IntelliJ/Lobby) whether auto-completion and other smart features work well (and conveniently) with multi-module packages?

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok. Generally speaking, I am very satisfied with the IDEA Mathematica plug-in. I do use completion, but I do not rely on it that much. For larger projects/files I find IDEA's [structure window](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmfZFPaInxE) really useful for hopping to functions definitions and usage declarations.

Comment: I meant that your input would be useful for @halirutan.  He's been basing the design mostly on my packages which are not that modular. It would be good to know if the new cross-module completion works well with others' packages as well. Absove I linked to the chatroom where all this was discussed.

Comment: There's also many new features for navigating projects. E.g. Command-B (on Mac, not sure about the equivalent on Windows)  will jump to any definition of the symbol, even if it's in a different module. It's better than the structure window.

Comment: @Szabolcs I looked into that chat-room and posted a comment.

Comment: Workbench/Eclipse has a similar function as the IntelliJ IDEA structure window called Outline.

Answer (score 12):

I tend to do this with an autogenerated loader file for all of my packages. This allows me to set up a single directory in my project called `"Packages"` and then the loader runs through the packages in that and sets up autoloading for their symbols.

This allows me to have a package structure like:

```
Packages
  + Pkg1.m
  + Pkg2.m
  Sub1
    + SubPkg1.m
  Sub2
    + SubPkg2.m
    SubSub1
      + SubSubPkg1.m
 etc.
```

And everything in `Pkg1` and `Pkg2` will be exposed at top level, everything in `SubPkg1` is in the context `Sub1`, everything in `SubPkg2` is in `Sub2`, and everything in `SubSub1` is in `SubSubPkg1`.

The key here, though, is that the loader first scans the head portion and declares all new symbols there as to be autoloaded. Then I expose all of the top-level package contexts to every other package.

The nice thing about this is that every package sees every other package so I don't have to manually manage dependencies. As long as you're not reusing symbol names across packages (I'd recommend against that anyway) you're fine.

The private implementations aren't shared across contexts.

One final thing before I dump a bunch of code is that this is very similar to how python rolls, except with less `import` management.

For those interested, here's a template of this kind of load-file (and since it's only ~300 LOC I've copied it below):

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Section:: *)
(*$Name Loader*)


BeginPackage["$Name`"]


$Name::usage="A head for the package (useful for messages)";


(* ::Subsection:: *)
(*Package Level Symbols*)


BeginPackage["`PackagePrivate`"]


$PackageName::usage="The name of the package";
$PackageDirectory::usage="The directory for the package";


$PackageListing::usage="The listing of packages";
$PackageContexts::usage="The list of contexts exposed to all packages";
$PackageDeclared::usage="Whether the package has been auto-loaded or not";


$PackageFileContexts::usage="The contexts for files in the package";
$DeclaredPackages::usage="The set of packages found and declared via the autoloader";
$LoadedPackages::usage="The set of loaded packages";


PackageExecute::usage="Executes something with the package contexts exposed";
PackageLoadPackage::usage="Loads a package via PackageExecute";
PackageLoadDeclare::usage="Declares a package";


PackageAppLoad::usage="Loads the entire package";
PackageAppGet::usage="";


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*Begin*)


Begin["`Private`"]


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*Constants*)


$PackageName="$Name";
$Name["Directory"]:=
  $PackageDirectory;
$PackageDirectory=
  DirectoryName@$InputFileName;


$PackagePackagesDirectory="Packages"


$Name["PackageListing"]:=$PackageListing;
$PackageListing=<||>;
$Name["Contexts"]:=$PackageContexts;
If[!ListQ@$PackageContexts,
  $PackageContexts=
    {
      "$Name`",
      "$Name`PackagePrivate`"
      }
  ];
$PackageDeclared=TrueQ[$PackageDeclared];


$Name["FileContexts"]:=$PackageFileContexts;
If[Not@AssociationQ@$PackageFileContexts,
  $PackageFileContexts=
    <||>
  ];
$Name["DeclaredPackages"]:=$DeclaredPackages;
If[Not@AssociationQ@$DeclaredPackages,
  $DeclaredPackages=
    <||>
  ];
$Name["LoadedPackages"]:=$LoadedPackages;
If[Not@ListQ@$LoadedPackages,
  $LoadedPackages={}
  ];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageFilePath*)


PackageFilePath[p__]:=
  FileNameJoin[Flatten@{
    $PackageDirectory,
    p
    }];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageExecute*)


PackageExecute[expr_]:=
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    Begin[$PackageContexts[[1]]];
    System`Private`NewContextPath@
      Prepend[
        $PackageContexts,
        "System`"
        ];,
    expr,
    System`Private`RestoreContextPath[];
    End[];
    ];
PackageExecute~SetAttributes~HoldFirst


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackagePullDeclarations*)


PackagePullDeclarationsAction//Clear
PackagePullDeclarationsAction[
  Hold[
    _Begin|_BeginPackage|
      CompoundExpression[_Begin|_BeginPackage,___]
    ]
  ]:=
  Throw[Begin];
PackagePullDeclarationsAction[e:Except[Hold[Expression]]]:=
  Sow@e;


PackagePullDeclarations[pkgFile_]:=
  pkgFile->
    Cases[
        Reap[
          With[{f=OpenRead[pkgFile]},
            Catch@
              Do[
                If[
                  Length[
                    ReadList[
                      f,
                      PackagePullDeclarationsAction@Hold[Expression],
                      1
                      ]
                    ]===0,
                    Throw[EndOfFile]
                  ],
                Infinity
                ];
            Close[f]
            ]
        ][[2,1]],
      s_Symbol?(
        Function[Null,
          Quiet[Context[#]===$Context],
          HoldAllComplete
          ]
          ):>
          HoldPattern[s],
      Infinity
      ]


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageLoadPackage*)


PackageLoadPackage[heldSym_,context_,pkgFile_->syms_]:=
  Block[{
    $loadingChain=
      If[ListQ@$loadingChain,$loadingChain,{}],
    $inLoad=TrueQ[$inLoad]
    },
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      System`Private`NewContextPath@$ContextPath,
      If[!MemberQ[$loadingChain,pkgFile],
        AppendTo[$loadingChain, pkgFile];
        With[{$$inLoad=$inLoad},
          $inLoad=True;
          Replace[Thread[syms,HoldPattern],
            Verbatim[HoldPattern][{s__}]:>Clear[s]
            ];
          If[Not@MemberQ[$ContextPath,context],
            $ContextPath=Prepend[$ContextPath,context];
            ];
          PackageAppGet[context,pkgFile];
          Unprotect[$LoadedPackages];
          AppendTo[$LoadedPackages, pkgFile];
          Protect[$LoadedPackages];
          ReleaseHold[heldSym]
          ]
        ],
      System`Private`RestoreContextPath[]
      ]
    ];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageDeclarePackage*)


PackageDeclarePackage[pkgFile_->syms_]:=
  With[{c=$Context},
    $DeclaredPackages[pkgFile]=syms;
    $PackageFileContexts[pkgFile]=c;
    Map[
      If[True,
        #:=PackageLoadPackage[#,c,pkgFile->syms]
        ]&,
      syms
      ]
    ];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageLoadDeclare*)


PackageLoadDeclare[pkgFile_String]:=
  If[!MemberQ[$LoadedPackages,pkgFile],
    If[!KeyMemberQ[$DeclaredPackages,pkgFile],
      PackageDeclarePackage@
        PackagePullDeclarations[pkgFile]
        ],
      PackageAppGet[pkgFile]
    ];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageAppLoad*)


$Name["Load", args___]:=
  PackageAppLoad[args]


packageAppLoad[dir_, listing_]:=
  With[
    {
      fileNames=
        Select[
          FileNames["*", dir],
          DirectoryQ@#||MatchQ[FileExtension[#], "m"|"wl"]&
          ]
      },
    Replace[
      Select[fileNames, 
        StringMatchQ[
          ToLowerCase@FileNameTake[#],
          "__pre__."~~("m"|"wl")
          ]&
        ],
      {f_}:>Get[f]
      ];
    PackageAppLoad[
      $PackageListing[listing]=
        Select[fileNames, StringFreeQ["__"]@*FileBaseName]
      ];
    Replace[
      Select[fileNames, 
        StringMatchQ[
          ToLowerCase@FileNameTake[#], 
          "__Post__."~~("m"|"wl")
          ]&
        ],
      {f_}:>Get[f]
      ];
    ];


PackageAppLoad[dir_String?DirectoryQ]:=
  If[StringMatchQ[FileBaseName@dir,(WordCharacter|"$")..],
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      Begin["`"<>FileBaseName[dir]<>"`"],
      AppendTo[$PackageContexts, $Context];
      packageAppLoad[dir, FileNameDrop[dir, FileNameDepth[$PackageDirectory]+1]],
      End[]
      ]
    ];
PackageAppLoad[file_String?FileExistsQ]:=
  PackageLoadDeclare[file];
PackageAppLoad[]:=
  PackageExecute@
    packageAppLoad[
      FileNameJoin@{$PackageDirectory, $PackagePackagesDirectory}, 
      $PackageName
      ];
PackageAppLoad~SetAttributes~Listable;


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*PackageAppGet*)


$Name["Get", f__]:=
  PackageAppGet[f];
PackageAppGet[f_]:=
  PackageExecute@
    With[{fBase = 
      If[FileExistsQ@f,
        f,
        PackageFilePath[$PackagePackagesDirectory, f<>".m"]
        ]
      },
      With[{cont = 
        Most@
          FileNameSplit[
            FileNameDrop[fBase, 
              FileNameDepth[PackageFilePath[$PackagePackagesDirectory]]
              ]
            ]},
        If[Length[cont]>0,
          Begin[StringRiffle[Append[""]@Prepend[""]@cont, "`"]];
          (End[];#)&@Get[fBase],
          Get[fBase]
        ]
      ]
    ];
PackageAppGet[c_,f_]:=
  PackageExecute[
    Begin[c];
    (End[];#)&@
      If[FileExistsQ@f,
        Get@f;,
        Get@PackageFilePath[$PackagePackagesDirectory, f<>".m"]
        ]
    ];


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*End*)


End[]


(* ::Subsubsection::Closed:: *)
(*EndPackage*)


EndPackage[]


(* ::Subsection:: *)
(*Load*)


If[!TrueQ[`PackagePrivate`$PackageDeclared],
  `PackagePrivate`PackageAppLoad[];
  `PackagePrivate`$PackageDeclared
  ]


EndPackage[]
```

Name that file `TestPackageLoader`, change `$Name` to `TestPackage`, then set up a directory that looks like this:

```
TestPackage
  + TestPackageLoader.wl
  Kernel
    + init.m
  Packages
    Pkg1.m
    Sub1
      Sub1.m
      Sub2
        Sub2.m
```

Put

```
<<TestPackage`TestPackageLoader`
```

in `init.m`

Put something like

```
Pkg1::usage="...";
Begin["`Private`"];
Pkg1[]:=Sub1[]
End[]
```

in `Pkg1.m`

And put a similar type of thing in `Sub1.m` and `Sub2.m`

When you call `` <<TestPackage` `` the following will happen:

- Autoloading will be configured for `Sub1`, `Sub2`, and `Pkg1` for when they're used
- When loaded, each symbol will know about the others
- Only `Pkg1` will be exposed in the top-level context

I've used this to good effect [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools), [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-ChemTools), [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools), and [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-PyTools), among many places, although my actual load files are much more fully featured (they include exception handling helpers, autocompletion helpers, dependency loaders, etc.).

Hopefully this at least provides inspiration for what *can* be done, even if it isn't directly useful

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I agree that the documentation for packages could be significantly improved as much of it seems to be folklore or scattered in various places. This really is a pity since once settling on a workflow I  have found the whole package idiom extremely powerful and IMO, the fact that it has changed so little for so long is testament to the soundness of the original design. Having said this, there are a couple of tweaks and mindsets needed to make the design fly:

1. Abandon all second argument usages of `BeginPackage`
2. Get into the habit of aligning package namespaces with directory layouts and then exploit mercilessly

My experience is that doing so allows your code to emerge thoroughly modularized together with flexible deployment opportunities. The following describes the set up and idiom I believe is intended by the WW file structure in your example (but with some minor personal customizations):

```
TestPackage
   Kernel
       init.m
   TestPackage.m
   Component1
      Component1.nb   (* foo, bar code defined here *)
      Component1.m
   Component2
        Component2.nb   (* foo2, bar2 code defined here *)
        Component2.m
        Subcomponent2 
            Subcomponent2.nb (* deeperFoo2, deeperBar2 code defined here  *)
            Subcomponent2.m
```

I have taken the liberty of  adding a third component, `Subcomponent2`, in order to emphasise  the possibility of increasingly nested folders as part of unlimited modularization. Curiously,  deeply nested examples seem rare (the deepest I have observed is 3 deep in the `` Parallel`Queue`FIFO `` package) but IMO this is what ultimately gives the package idiom its scalability and flexibility (I've often wondered if *Mathematica* could significantly reduce its run-time footprint with more granulated packaging in its `` System` `` context).

The important point to note is that this directory structure directly maps to the contexts of the public functions when the package is loaded. So for example,  the following shows the full context names of the public functions when the "relevant" package is loaded

```
TestPackage`Component1`foo
TestPackage`Component1`bar
TestPackage`Component2`foo2
TestPackage`Component2`bar2
TestPackage`Component2`Subcomponent2`deeperFoo2
TestPackage`Component2`Subcomponent2`deeperBar2
```

A user won't need to use the full context names as illustrated shortly after fleshing out some details  (with any clarifications if needed later):

---

- The top level is identical to what WW generates except that instead of a file *Component1.m* I prefer to have a folder *Component1* that contains *Component1.m*. This is because I like to leave the option open for these subpackages to contain their own *Kernel* folder, *Tests*, *DataRepositories* etc. Further, these *.m* files I like to generate from initialized cells in corresponding *.nb* files since I prefer to develop code in the front-end. Of course many other workflows  edit the *.m* file directly  in the frontend, *WolframWorkbench*, *IntelliJIDEA*  or your favourite editor.
- Note these extra files/folders don't affect the calling of these packages and to see this it helps to internalize `Needs` control flow: Firstly, for `Needs` to recognize these packages the `TestPackage` directory needs to be on `$Path` or else called with a second argument : as in   `` Needs["TestPackage`", "path-to-TestPackageDirectory"] ``.  `Needs` resolves any named package to a directory before first trying to load a contained *Kernel/init.m* file or  if that fails,  a *.m* file with the same name  (`FindFile` can be used  to check if the correct file is going to be loaded). For example, assuming `$Path` is appropriately set,  the following invocations  loads the corresponding file.

  `` Needs["TestPackage`"] ``
  _______<sub>*TestPackage/Kernel/init.m*</sub>

  `` Needs["TestPackage`Component1`"] ``
  _______<sub>*TestPackage/Component1/Component1.m*</sub>

  `` Needs["TestPackage`Component2`"] ``
  _______<sub>*TestPackage/Component2/Component2.m*</sub>

  `` Needs["TestPackage`Component2`Subcomponent2`"] ``
  _______<sub>*TestPackage/Component2/Subcomponent2/Subcomponent2.m*</sub>

In practice, these subpackages don't need to be loaded individually (but having the option to do so adds flexibility in setting up certain dependencies) since this is done  automatically through the magic of `DeclarePackage` - IMO  one of the most underrated and important functions in *Mathematica*.  On invoking `` Needs["TestPackage`"] ``  the file *TestPackage/Kernel/init.m* is loaded which, containing  `` Get["TestPackage`TestPackage`"] `` loads in *TestPackage/TestPackage.m* which hopefully contains the following `DeclarePackage` commands (there used to be, I think[?] , an old Roman script that produced these `DeclarePackage` blocks automatically)

```
DeclarePackage["TestPackage`Component1`", {"foo","bar"}];
DeclarePackage["TestPackage`Component2`", {"foo2","bar2"}];
DeclarePackage["TestPackage`Component2`Subcomponent2`", {"deeperFoo2","deeperBar2"}]}
```

These `DeclarePackage` calls load the subpackages on a needs basis by setting the `Stub` attribute  to the variables and adding the sub packages' contexts  to `$ContextPath` (thereby making the entering of full context names unnecessary). So, for example,  entering  `deeperFoo2`  now automatically calls `` Needs["TestPackage`Component2`Subcomponent2`"] `` which loads *TestPackage/Component2/Subcomponent2/Subcomponent2.m* and `deeperFoo2`'s definition(s).

The reason this is so worthwhile is that having swathes of code loaded on a just-in-time basis means reaping (compounding) run-time benefits from all your modularizing efforts (not to mention making any end-user `Needs` usage redundant).

In a well-known white paper, [*Building Large Software Systems in Mathematica*](http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/workbench/building-large-software-systems-in-mathematica.pdf?4ae6ee529e4e0d5967853e9a6db23dfe91a58aca1ed09a655b640563c6fbad098a99cee4a215), a comprehensive list of the benefits of modularization is provided but without mentioning the extra benefits obtained by having finely granulated packages (backed by `DeclarePackage`) significantly lesson a run-time footprint. It seems inevitable that this will become increasingly important for new applications in the cloud, on Raspberry Pi and parallel kernels etc.

- An example of the aforementioned alignment between directories and `BeginPackage` usage is *Component2.nb* containing initialization cells with the sequence (Note, `Needs` is expecting this package structure when loading, `Get` doesn't)

  ```
  BeginPackage["TestPackage`Component2`"]

    usage::foo2="foo2[var] does this";

      Begin["Private`"]

         foo2[_]:="does this"

      End[]

  EndPackage[]
  ```
- Internal `Needs` calls (*not* using the second argument of `BeginPackage`)  can then be used to handle all required package dependencies.
- I have used this set up to implement various use cases (e.g. using/exposing common subpackages, versioning etc), *without* "unweildy" manipulations of `$Path`, `$ContextPath` etc . At least, I have never found this set-up wanting with what seem like common and previously described requirements (but I suspect I might be missing something or have misinterpreted these other use-cases given an apparent need for a "next generation" packaging system).
- There is actually a further extension I have in my development set-up that redefines `Needs` mainly to handle the different imperatives of end-users and developers. This extension is for development and doesn't make it into deployed packages ( [or posts] given that packages etc really ought not to modify system functions). Maybe  future built-in functions will include these developer capabilities but irrespective, IMO the current package idiom can already take you a very long way.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know of an actual package that uses the above so I can download all the files and see better what to do? I can't get it to work just from the description above.

Comment: No, but I did have some code that generates all these which I'll see if I can dig up - but the layout as described should work ...?

Comment: Well of course, hundreds/thousands? of actual packages use the above layout (look in Mathematica's internal files)! Naturally all my own packages use this idiom as well but I meant a minimal/toy one at hand to quickly upload/illustrate but it seems you've got it to work in your other question (I will update a toy one here in due course).