# Symbol appears in multiple contexts when loading package

Tags: packages, symbols, contexts, application

I'm building a Mathematica application "APPStestI" that contains three packages: SUBappsA.m, SUBappsB.m, SUBappsC.m and APPStestI.m. Where APPStestI.m is the main package; SUBappsA.m and SUBappsB.m contains some functions and SUBappsC.m stores the values of the constants used by other packages.

> init.m

```
Get[ "APPStestI`APPStestI`"]
Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsA`"]
Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsB`"]
Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsC`"]
```

> APPStestI.m

```
BeginPackage["APPStestI`"]

   Print [Style[" Mathematica application ","Text"]];

EndPackage[]
```

> SUBappsA.m

In this package we use the stored value of x.

```
BeginPackage["APPStestI`SUBappsA`"]

  Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsC`"]
  Unprotect["SUBappsA`*"];    
  ClearAll["SUBappsA`*"]; 

  funI::usage = "funI[ x]"

Begin["`Private`"] (* Begin Private Context *)

  funI[xp_] := Module[ {yp}, yp = xp^2+x; yp + 1 ]

End[] (* End Private Context *)

  Protect["SUBappsA`*"];

EndPackage[]
```

> SUBappsB.m

In this package we use the stored value of WW.

```
BeginPackage["APPStestI`SUBappsB`"]

  Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsA`"]
  Get[ "APPStestI`SUBappsC`"]
  Unprotect["SUBappsB`*"];
  ClearAll["SUBappsB`*"];

  funII::usage = "funII[w] computes a simple function."

Begin["`Private`"] 

  funII[ wp_] := Module[ {zp}, zp = wp^3+ funI[WW]; zp + 1]

End[]

  Protect["SUBappsB`*"];

EndPackage[]
```

> SUBappsC.m

```
BeginPackage["APPStestI`SUBappsC`"]

  Unprotect["SUBappsC`*"];
  ClearAll["SUBappsC`*"];

  y::usage= "5" 
  WW::usage= "10" 
  x::usage= "3" 
  z::usage= "4" 

Begin["`Private`"] 

  {  y = 5,  WW = 10,  x = 3,  z = 4 };

End[] 

  Protect["SUBappsC`*"];

EndPackage[]
```

Then loading APPStestI the following is shown:

```
<< APPStestI`
```

> z::shdw: Symbol z appears in multiple contexts {APPStestI`SUBappsC`,Global`}; definitions in context APPStestI`SUBappsC` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

The application performs the operations correctly, but I can not solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Minor issues:**

- `Get` always loads while `Needs` only if needed so if someone calls your init.m file then *SUBappsC.m* will be loaded 3 times. You probablt don't want that.
- `` Unprotect["SUBappsB`*"] `` - this and friends won't do anything because this context does not exist at all.

**The main problem** is that your *SUBappsC.m* creates `x, y, z, WW` in `` APPStestI`SUBappsC` `` which is one of exported contexts. (It will appear on a `$ContextPath` after `EndPackage[]`.

Packages should not export dummy variables because of collisions/shadowing problems. That is why `` Begin["`Private`"] `` is used. You however need to share them as they are not just dummy variables. (giving them more meanigful names would be a good idea if they are meant to float around your implementation files)

The common approach to creating symbols which are shared between implementation files but not outside is to use an additional context that is invoked in each file.

Let me show you a problematic code

[image]

and a proposed solution:

```
Remove[z]; (*or restart the kernel*)
z = 1;     (*again global*)
```

---

```
  (*First package*)
BeginPackage["MyPackage1`"];

    BeginPackage["`Common`"];
        z::usage = "here's z from MyPackage1`Common`"; 
        (*symbols exported to a shared context*)
    EndPackage[];


    Begin["`Private`"];
        (*whatever*)
    End[];

EndPackage[];
```

---

```
  (*And in anotherpackage:*)
BeginPackage["MyPackage2`"];
    (*I would use the same MyPackage1` across many subpackages unless there is a reason not to. 
      Here I created another context just to show that it won't break our scheme*)

    Needs @ "MyPackage1`";   (*adds it to a $ContextPath, nothing there anyway*)
    Needs @ "MyPackage1`Common`"; (*z's here*)

    Begin["`Private`"];
        Print[z::usage] (*could it work? yep*)    
    End[];

EndPackage[];
```

As I said, I'd not use so many different nested context but maybe you have a good reason to do so. Then you need to be in control.

More reading:

- [Declaring Package with dependencies in multiples files?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176434/5478)
- [How to design re-usable sub-modules?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176627/5478)
- [How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/5478)
- [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/5478)

Comment: Does anyone ever -- or rather is it advisable to treat a package like a class object (in OO programming) and make package parameters private but accessible only through methods?  E.g. `getParam["x"]`, `setParam["x", 3]`, etc. It also allows one to validate assignments and maintain dependencies.  (This seemed to be a common style in Obj-C, AFAIR.  But my days of serious programming are long gone.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think b3m2a1 does a lot of related stuff and can say more. I'd say it makes sense if you have a strong background in OOP. I don't and it was always a pain for me, and not very idiomatic. Moreover I mostly deal with GUI and I need a flexible access to symbols for `Dynamic` purposes, so I don't have time to set all needed methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100369/discussion-between-felix-crazzolara-and-kuba).