# How do you set up private contexts shared between sub-packages?

Tags: packages

I have a fairly large project that logically splits into several subunits, and for reasons of testing, documentation, and discoverability, I would like to make each subunit its own (sub-)package, like so:

```
PillsyPackage`
  |
  +- `SubpackageA`
  |
  +- `SubpackageB`
```

However, all of these sub-packages need to share some private functions (they all work on the same data structures which should be opaque, so I want the accessors to be private).

Ideally, I'd like to give the sub-packages access to `PillsyPackage`Private`. What's the best way to do this in terms of syntax and file layout?

Comment: "need to share some private functions" - in the Standard Add-on Packages, this was solved by setting up a `Common.m` package containing the private functions that will be shared among other packages that need those functions.

Comment: Use new-style packages. Description [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176434/declaring-package-with-dependencies-in-multiples-files/176489#176489).

Comment: The drawback with applying a `Common.m` solution is that JITL (Just-in-time-loading via `DeclarePackage`) doesn't support a "names file". The drawback with a new-style package is that it is not scalable in terms of supporting JITL. If these two aspects are important (and they aren't always) but I argue they increase in importance with the size of a system so they might be for a "fairly large project". I am putting out shortly an extension of `BeginPackage-EndPackage` (which I will link to) that addresses this very issue.

Comment: @RonaldMonson `DeclarePackage` is an old style of doing this, which is no longer used, at least not internally in the company. The current mechanism is to use the paclet symbol autoloading and paclet project loading, which plays well with new-style packages.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes I suspected as much as checking a few weeks ago its vestiges seem to be only in Mma's authortools. But I wonder if something important has been lost here - at least I am yet to see how the `Stub` attribute transfers as previously discussed ( I'm not just talking about public functions but private ones the OP mentions e.g. what if you want these privately shared functions to incorporate JITL? can the current mechanism handle this?). My sense is that this new mechanism is tilted towards public functions. Naturally, I don't fully understand paclet symbol autoloading so ...

Comment: ... there may well be this functionality but equally, as none of this is officially documented or a roadmap advertised for its polishing/scaling/release - here's hoping! - I guess we are constrained with what we currently have. I guess the same applies to `BeginPackage/EndPackage` whose ongoing presence seems unlikely to be deprecated anytime soon but I agree, to have a flowchart for what idioms might be reasonably adopted by developers in given situations would be great.

Comment: I do this in my own packages by creating an autoloader for all the symbols that sets up the right context path. It works incredibly well and is easy to extend. Can describe more if there’s interest.

Comment: @b3m2a1 That is exactly the sort of thing I'm interested in learning more about. Could you blow it up into an answer? You'll get at least one vote out of it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do this. I have a standard load script I build from template for all of my packages. You can see one for my main development package [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/BToolsLoader.m).

What it does then is look for a directory called `Packages` in the top-level package directory (although there are config options to change this, if I remember correctly).

Then if the directory structure looks like:

```
MyPackage
 Packages
  + pkg1.m
  + pkg2.m
  A
   + subpkg1.m
  B
   + subpkg2.m
```

I'll get out three contexts, `` "MyPackage`" ``, `` "MyPackage`A" ``, `` "MyPackage`B`" ``. The way I then make all the symbols in each see eachother when they load is that I use lazy-loading. So first I scan through all the found package files and register all the symbol names in the appropriate context and setup an `OwnValues` pattern so that when they're called for the first time they will load the package they're declared in using a special `PackageGet` function. This is done by the [`PackageDeclare`](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/35553ab139d7362b89826f2b5b20d37998e2abdc/BToolsLoader.m#L506) function in the load script.

That `PackageGet` function then uses `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` and `` System`Private`NewContextPath `` and `` System`Private`RestoreContextPath `` to set up a `$ContextPath` that looks like:

```
{
 "MyPackage`",
 "MyPackage`A`",
 "MyPackage`B`",
 "MyPackage`PackageScope`Private`" (* I put a bunch of utility functions here *)
 }
```

This way each symbol sees each other when they load, but no private declarations or anything like that.

I haven't fully described what I do, as I also have ways to handle circular dependencies and things, but this is a basic overview that perhaps one might implement for themselves.

I have found it to be a useful and powerful idiom reminiscent of the way python handles package loading.