# What to be aware when using new-style package?

Tags: packages

A new package format is described [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176489/12).  This format does not use [`BeginPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html) and [`Begin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin.html). Instead, each package file is scanned before its contents are evaluated, and the context of each symbol is decided beforehand.

What are some of the things to be aware when using this package format?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I will give a FAQ-style presentation of some things I became aware of while transitioning one of my packages to this format. [Leonid's description of the new package format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176489/12) is required reading before looking at this FAQ!

#### How are contexts assigned to symbols in the package?

In traditional packages, [symbols are looked up from `$ContextPath`, and if not found, created in `$Context`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12). It is always the current value of `$ContextPath` and `$Context` that determines what a symbol name in the package file refers to.

`BeginPackage` and `Begin` simply manipulate `$ContextPath` and `$Context`. When they are evaluated, the value of these system variables will change. `End` and `EndPackage` change it back. The process is dynamic, and happens as each line in the package file is evaluated one by one.

In new-style packages, the context of each symbol is decided *before* the contents of the package file are evaluated.  Mathematica will scan all files in the package directory for the `Package`, `PackageExport`, `PackageImport`, `PackageScope` directives, and uses them to pre-determine the context of each symbol that appears in the package.

The package contents are evaluated only *after* this has happened.

#### Which contexts are symbols created in?

A private symbol in a file named `Foo` that is part of the package `` MyApp` ``  will go in the context `` MyApp`Foo`PackagePrivate` `` .

A package scope symbol, declared with `PackageScope`, will go in `` MyApp`PackageScope` `` .

An exported symbol, declared with `PackageExport`, will go in `` MyApp` `` .

#### How do `Package`, `PackageExport`, `PackageImport`, `PackageScope` evaluate?

They do not evaluate at all. They are not expressions and hence they also cannot be terminated by a `;` which is a short form for `CompoundExpression`.

They behave more like directives than symbols.  They simply signal to the parser how to assign contexts to each symbol in the file.  This assignment of contexts takes place before any evaluation is done.

This means that e.g. this is not valid:

```
PackageExport /@ {"symbol1", "symbol2"}
```

Instead we must write

```
PackageExport["symbol1"]
PackageExport["symbol2"]
```

`PackageExport` never evaluates as a symbol.

#### In what order are files loaded?

A new-style package is usually made up by multiple files, each containing `` Package["MyApp`"] ``.  If the loading of one of these files is triggered with `Get` or `Needs`, all other files that belong to the `` MyApp` ``  package will be loaded.

After the first file was loaded, the rest will be loaded in alphabetical order.

The first file would either have the same name as the package itself (e.g. `MyApp.m` for `` MyApp` `` ) or it would be explicitly loaded in `Kernel/init.m`.

#### What are valid file names?

Since file names are mapped to context names, file names must also be valid context names.  This means that `_` or a space cannot be used in file names. File names may not start with a digit.

It is a natural thought to try to control loading order by prepending digits to file names. But such names are not valid.

#### What is the value of `$Context` and `$ContextPath` during package loading?

In Mathematica 11.0 and later, the value of `$Context` and `$ContextPath` correspond to the file that is currently being loaded.

For example, if the current file is `Main.m` and the package name is `` MyApp` `` , then

```
$Context === "MyApp`Main`PackagePrivate`"
$ContextPath === {"MyApp`PackageScope`", "MyApp`", "System`"}
```

*However, in Mathematica 10.x, `$Context` and `$ContextPath` do not change at all during loading.* They retain the value they had before package loading (e.g. `` $Context === Global` ``  and the usual `$ContextPath`).

What this means in practice is that in Mathematica 10.x, `ToExpression["x"]` would create the symbol `x` in the `` Global` ``  context (or whatever was the context before package loading) instead of the package's private context.

The same is true for `<*expr*>` included in [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)s.

Finally, if the package loads another file with `Get`, all symbols in that file will be created in `` Global` `` , not in the package's private context.

#### What is the value of `$InputFile` and `$Input` when loading new-style packages?

In Mathematica 11.0 and later, `$InputFile` is always set to the specific file that is currently being loaded. It is different for each file that makes up the package.

In Mathematica 10.x, `$InputFile` is always set to *the first file* of the package, regardless of which file is currently being loaded.

`$Input` is always set to the name of the first file, in all versions between M10.0–M11.3.

#### Can we give a definition to `Package`?

Each file that is part of the package must include

```
Package["MyContext`"]
```

As explained before `Package` is just a directive, and does not have a definition. We might, in principle, give it a definition, and hope that it will evaluate in each package file.

This, however, does not happen. `Package` and related directives are removed from the file before its contents are evaluated.

Comment: Great job of outlining the more subtle points of new-style packages. Big +1.

Comment: It seems like in new format files constituting package have to have '.m' extension. Files with '.wl' extension are ignored except the main package file.

Answer (score 11):

I would add to this that it is undocumented for a reason, unfinished, and may break in the future.

Comment: That, of course, technically applies to any undocumented feature. The problem is that there is an endless list of undocumented features which are in reality essential to developing packages with any sanity (from `WithLocalSettings` to not so long ago paclets themselves). Realistically one cannot do without undocumented features. Thus we need to consider the risk in each individual case.

Comment: Personally, I am quite conservative in this and use only features which have been stable for a long time and are used internally. This is the case with new-style packages (they worked mostly the same in v10 over 6 years ago, and are used by many internal components). I assume there is a reason you posted this, and there are plans, or at least discussions, to make drastic changes. I very much hope that there will be a reasonable way forward for those who have invested in this feature.