# Unimport wolfram language package

Tags: packages

In Wolfram Language, `Import["file.wl"]` can import external wolfram package, Is it reversible?

Can I unimport some packages? In other means Unset all the Function, Variable which is Set when `Import`?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem http://xyproblem.info/  There may be a good reason to want to unload a package, but I cannot think of one. What's your *actual* problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please, and explain what you are trying to achieve by "unimporting"?

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to load a package is [`Needs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html) or [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html), not [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html).

No, loading is not reversible. The only way to restore the pre-package-loading state robustly is to restart the kernel with [`Quit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quit.html).

Alternatively, you may remove the package's context from the [`$ContextPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html). This will effectively hide the package's symbols. However, this does not unload the package. The package's symbols will still be usable, but they must be referred to with the full context.

> In other means Unset all the Function, Variable which is Set when Import?

Note that *loading a package* may do a lot more than create definitions. Clearing definitions is not a safe way to "unload" it.

Comment: One potentially useful purpose might be for testing or resolving namespace collisions without using `Quit[]`.

Comment: @RolfMertig Yes, that's a good use. However, in that case the solution is to remove the context from the `$ContextPath`, not to try to clear definitions.

Comment: @Szablcs What if you want to cleanly reload a package while developing it? Using Get again is not always enough. And I somehow don't like to Quit and restart the kernel. Too slow. As so much ...

Comment: @RolfMertig That's not what the OP was asking though. It may be what they wanted, but it's not what they asked. This is why I said it looks like an XY problem. The `Import` thing makes it even more unclear. Some context is needed from the OP.

Comment: @RolfMertig When faced with a question with this, and the OP does not clarify (as here), there is no ideal solution. One can answer literally, as I did ("it is not possible to unload") or one may start guessing at what OP *really* wanted. That guesswork can be a waste of time, is likely not the best solution anyway for the OP's actual problem, and in the worst case [the answer may end up being copied again and again and completely misused in outright dangerous ways](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/222839/12).

Comment: I agree. BTW: Isn't `Import["package.wl"]` exactly identical to `Get["package.wl"]` (except $Path dependencies, i.e., 
`Import@FindFile@"ComputerArithmetic\`"` does the same as `Get@"ComputerArithmetic\`"`) ?

Comment: @RolfMertig Well, `Import` appears to work, but it's not designed for this ... so we shouldn't use it for this, or risk subtle things breaking. Is there any reason to use it? OP is probably coming from Python and misundesrstood what Import does. I think the main argument against is that it is not designed for this purpose. Who knows what can go wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109480/discussion-between-rolf-mertig-and-szabolcs).

Comment: Things I know about: 1) in not-so-old versions `Import` could not be safely used in `init.m` (I think this was fixed) 2) Import has high overhead (ok, not a big deal) 3) Import determined the `FileFormat` partially based on the first few bytes, and not solely based on the file extension. Is it guaranteed that it will always load it was a `"Package"` and not as some other import format? 4) Something I suspected might go wrong, but didn't: does it load [new-style packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184711/12) correctly? (It turns out, it does.)

Answer (score 3):

If a package only consists of definitions, does not load subpackages and does not attach the `Locked` attribute to its symbols, then it is possible to remove its definitions by

```
unLoad[context_String /; StringEndsQ[context, "`"]] := (
  Unprotect; (Unprotect[#]; Remove[#]) & /@ {context <> "*", 
    context <> "*`*"}; $ContextPath = 
   DeleteCases[$ContextPath, context];
  )
```

This can be tested by, e.g.,

```
 Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"];
 unLoad["ComputerArithmetic`"];
```

Now `` Names["ComputerArithmetic`*"] `` gives an empty list