# Does Workbench support "new" package format?

Tags: packages, workbench

The format described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176434/declaring-package-with-dependencies-in-multiples-files/176489#176489) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184711/what-to-be-aware-when-using-new-style-package) seems to be a big step forward from `BeginPackage`/`EndPackage` structure and is apparently widely used in Mathematica itself.

From my experience Workbench does not currently support it (symbol navigation does not work as well as debugging etc).

If the answer is "no" — does anyone has the experience with some IDE and "new package format"?

I've checked [Idea plugin](https://wlplugin.halirutan.de) (which I actually have paid version), but it seem to have the same problem: symbol navigation does not work across files.

VSCode has very limited support for Wolfram Language (and getting language server to run stably seems next to impossible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With IntelliJ, you can get symbol navigation working across files with the new package format. I use it regularly.  Make sure all symbols you want to include have a usage message, then it will work.

Comment: To be clear, what is needed is for symbols to have a usage message and not for them to be public. In other words, you might want to add a usage message to all `PackageScope` symbols, not just `PackageExport` ones. While at first this may feel like a chore, it is quite useful to do it because you can also get a small documentation popup in case you forgot what the function does ...

Comment: @Szabolcs hahaha !!!!  Thanks for the advice!

But this behaviour seems a bit strange for me. Especially because almost all my usage messages are set via GeneralUtilities`SetUsage.

I wonder if this by design of the plugin.

Comment: @Szabolcs BTW it seems anything will do, not just usage:

```
tst::anything="asda
```

Comment: You can bring up that point to @halirutan. As far as I can tell, with new-style packages it is easy to determine what symbols should be considered even without a usage message, so maybe this can be improved. The usage message thing was used mainly because with traditional packages there's no good way to identify what is or isn't public.

Comment: Also, if you want to make use of new-style package, be aware of this warning: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238475/12 As for myself, I am too deeply invested in the new format to abandon it now, but after seeing this comment, I'd be wary ...

Comment: I'v very well aware about the warning but new-style packages are much more suitable for multi-file packages, especially for rapid development.

Considering usage messages I thought it is a relic of traditional package format.

Does @halirutan read this site?

Thank you again.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on GitHub and explaining your use case. It is not possible to notify people who are not involved in this thread.

Comment: @Szabolcs Why don't you convert your comments into an answer?

Comment: Workbench also doens't support "autoloading" all files in the FrontEnd, like it does this for standard package definitions (i.e. I need to evaluate "Get" each time I save some changes in workbench files for multifile package) - but at the same time code in the main file "MyPackage\MyPackage.m" is loaded automatically after saving it in Workbench