# Are new-style packages compatible with the Wolfram Paclet Repository?

Tags: packages, paclets

The package I'm developing is getting hard to navigate as it gets larger.  I've started experimenting with using the new-style package format described in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184711/what-to-be-aware-when-using-new-style-package) to break it up to subfiles.  But now I'm worried: is this format compatible with the even-newer [Wolfram Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/), particularly in light of [@ItaiSeggev's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238475/6358)?

Comment: (+1) Is there a new version of your package available now, @Chris K?

Comment: @E.Chan-López No, just working on one and thought it might be a good time to reorganize, but not if it is incompatible with the Paclet Repository!

Comment: Your question seems interesting to me. I'm moving forward with a package, but now that I see your question, I would like someone to answer in detail if there are any incompatibility issues for the package repository.  Thanks for your response, @Chris K!

Comment: why do you need to change to new style of packaging in order to split your large m file to smaller number of m files?  You can do that and still use the original package style. See this [note](https://12000.org/my_notes/how_to_write_package_in_mathematica/index.htm) as an example.

Comment: I also would not use new packaging style without having an official documentation about it at Wolfram web site.  I have not seen such document so far.

Comment: **to break it up to subfiles** You can also see [Declaring Package with dependencies in multiples files](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3099118?p_p_auth=Jx6b09zo)

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the info on splitting up packaged code.  Maybe my question still applies, are these compatible with the WPR?

Comment: @ChrisK I never done a paclet before myself. I am still at the stage of learning how to make a Mathematica package right :). May be someone else would know. I would think it should work in paclet  if you split the files.  I've seen number of packages using paclet which has many files in it. See MaTeX package for example.

Comment: Same, very interested in the answer to this question. I am building a paclet for my company and it is now too big for a single package file and i need to split it. Which one is the best approach and compatible with new paclet system.

Comment: @user13892 - you should definitely use the existing and documented method of making a multi-file package.  Here is a basic example of a multi-file paclet using the documented package format: https://github.com/antononcube/WL-AssociationRuleLearning-paclet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "new" package format does seem to be supported by the paclet repository:

```
In[1]:= PacletInstall["WolframInstitute/Hypergraph"];

In[2]:= ReadLine@FindFile["WolframInstitute`Hypergraph`"]

Out[2]= "Package[\"WolframInstitute`Hypergraph`\"]"
```

I have to mention that splitting a package into multiple files is very possible using the normal documented package format (the one that uses [`BeginPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html) instead of [`Package`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Package.html)).