# How do I make all the external contexts accessible within subcontexts of my package?

Tags: packages, contexts, paclets

I have a package file `MyPackage.wl` it has the following commands:

```
BeginPackage["Me`MyPackage`",{"ExternalContext1`","ExternalContext2`"}]
...
Needs["Me`MyPackage`Internal`"];
...
EndPackage[];
```

Now within `Internal.wl` it has the following commands:

```
BeginPackage["Me`MyPackage`Internal`",{"Me`MyPackage`"}];
...
EndPackage[];
```

Now I can access the "Me`MyPackage`Internal`", "ExternalContext1`" and "ExternalContext2`" symbols inside `MyPackage.wl` but within `Internal.wl` I can only access "Me`MyPackage`" symbols but not "ExternalContext1`" and "ExternalContext2`".

So why are the contexts "ExternalContext1`" and "ExternalContext2`" not being added to the `$ContextPath` inside `Internal.wl`. I can always start `Internal.wl` by:

```
BeginPackage["Me`MyPackage`Internal`",{"ExternalContext1`","ExternalContext2`","Me`MyPackage`"}];
```

and it would work but as I add more and more `ExternalContexts` and there are more and more subcontexts, I don't want to keep updating this list inside every single subpackage. What is the better way of doing this?

Comment: closely related: [Second argument of BeginPackage with nested package loading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115502/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Do you know about the "HiddenImport" and "PrimaryContext" properties in the newer Paclet System's PacletObject[...]. Can you explain what they are and how they work if you know?

Comment: I only found this: [What are Package` context symbols for?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/what-are-package-context-symbols-for) Never used it though.

Answer (score 2):

BeginPackage["pak1`",{"pak2"}] loads pak1 and pak2, but no package that pak2 needs. You can see this by e.g.:

```
BeginPackage["external`"]
$ContextPath
EndPackage[]

BeginPackage["context1`", {"external`"}]
$ContextPath
EndPackage[]
```

And then:

```
BeginPackage["internal`", {"context1`"}]
$ContextPath
EndPackage[]

internal`

{"internal`", "context1`", "System`"}
```

"external"`is not loaded.

To load also packages that a needed package needs, you may define a variable "cPath" that contains the loaded packages like:

```
BeginPackage["context1`", {"external`"}];
cPath = $ContextPath;
EndPackage[];

BeginPackage["internal`", {"context1`"}]
Needs /@ context1`cPath;
$ContextPath
EndPackage[]
```

This returns:

```
context1`
{"external`", "internal`", "context1`", "System`"}
```

Now "external`" is also loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I am keeping a variable to keep track of contexts as you suggested. But I am not accepting the answer in case their is a more builtin paclet way of doing this.