# Using ClipPlanes with AnatomyData

Tags: curated-data, anatomy

Suppose I render a simple eyeball:

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightEyeball"]]
```

[image: Anatomy plot of eyeball]

but want to cut it in half using `ClipPlanes`, for instance to eliminate the left half of the eyeball.

By what principled method do I know how to specify the plane?  I tried the obvious

```
ClipPlanes -> {1,0,0,0}
```

and

```
{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
```

without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course `ClipPlanes` works here. The problem is that you had mistakenly assumed the `PlotRange`:

```
eyeball = AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightEyeball"]];

pr = PlotRange[eyeball]
   {{-43.6181, -17.298}, {-166.051, -138.829}, {1504.96, 1531.19}}
```

Thus,

```
Show[eyeball, 
     ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[Mean[Transpose[pr]], {1, -1} IdentityMatrix[3][[{2, 3}]]]]
```

[image: eyeball cross-section]

Comment: I didn't know how to get the PlotRange of the object.  Simple!  Thanks so much.  (Accept)

Comment: Another way of finding the center of the eyeball is with `EntityValue[eyeball, "EnclosingSphere"][[1]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Do you know of a place where this functionality of `PlotRange` is documented?

Comment: @Lukas, I do not believe it is documented, but [it's been around for a long while](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22868).